# Using MapView to display a map

Tags: android, android-mapview

I'm trying to display a map in my android app, I've followed article below

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#install_and_configure_the_google_play_services_sdk

but activity started and map not displayed

Below is my mainfest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>


<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<!--
 The following two permissions are not required to use
 Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyACHHKBCSoG5ZEGbNYgMhKWSsZrV3loKek" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.hotel.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.hotel.OptionsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_options"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.Hotel" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.Hotel" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.hotel.Reservation"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_reservation" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.hotel.Reservations_Activity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_reservations_" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.hotel.ReservationDetails"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_reservation_details" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.hotel.SearchByStatus"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_search_by_status" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.hotel.SearchByHotel"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_search_by_hotel" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.hotel.ResApplication"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_res_application" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.hotel.Map"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_map" >
    </activity>


</application>
```

this is the activity code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

Comment: Did you get any error or check your API key? becoz you told _but activity started and map not displayed_

Comment: Check for a different map key, may be something went wrong while generating key.....

Comment: Hey @SimplePlan, how r u bro ???? :)

Comment: @SalmanKhan hi whats up?? i love sallu bhai.

Comment: hahaha, I have added you on google+ bro, just check it "Manish Bhai" :P

Comment: Dears thanks a lot it was the API Key